# Adding sub menu to Management menu

Tags: 7, views, routes

I'm trying to add a sub-menu under administration, for example:

Management:

- ......
- Content
- Structure
- ......
- My test (sub menu under administration)
  - My view 1 (a view that I created)
  - My view 2 (another view that I created)

Under structure-> menu, I see that I can create a new menu and add link to existing menues, but I cannot understand how can I add a sub menu to Management.
**Note:** I'm using Drupal 7.

**Edit:**
I added a link (My test) under management (Like in @Clive's answer) with path `admin/test`
under `My Test` I created another link with path admin/test/form-view-test-3 and also gave that path to the view.

[image]

When I click on `My menu` I what to see a list of subcategories, in my case `Some view`.
Instead Test 3 (The View) appears as overlay tab and I see the list of admin menus.

[image: Click on my test]

Comment: Are you trying to add another menu as Sub Menu in Management Menu ?

Comment: Yes. you see the edit

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to admin/structure/menu/manage/management; you'll see all the links currently in the menu.
2. Click "Add link"
3. Fill in the title, path and any other relevant data.
4. Click "Save"
5. Re-order the menu items if necessary
6. Repeat the process for as many links as you need to place under the new top-level item you just created.
7. If you're using the Admin Menu module, you might need to flush caches before changes take effect (but you might not).

Comment: I did what you wrote above, but it still doesn't work for me. Please see the edit.

Comment: To address your edit: you'll need to create the root path programatically using `hook_menu()`. The `page callback` will be [`system_admin_menu_block`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_admin_menu_block/7). See [`system_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_menu/7) for several examples