# new admin menu doesn't display on page

Tags: 7, navigation

I followed a tutorial to create an admin menu: [Adding sub menu to Management menu](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107651/adding-sub-menu-to-management-menu#answer-107652). However I still cannot see my new menu on my page. Then I download a module named [Administration menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_menu). I found my new menu item on the navbar when I use this module. Here is the screenshot:
[image]

All the menu in pink circle are old, the only new menu item is called "Product Substitue." But I cannot find on the page.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Or any tutorial? Thank you~

Comment: Did you flush all caches already?

Comment: @longboardnode Yes, already flushed several times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the same information rendered in different ways:

The menu along the top is quite simply reading from the database for any link in that menu.

The page is constructing itself based on the hierarchy of the hook_menu implementation. You're going to need to implement hook_menu for your new link to get it to show on the 'page' version of the menu.

Comment: Ok. So...what you mean is I have to write a custom module for this menu, right?

Comment: That's correct. Unfortunately simply adding a link to the menu in the UI won't cause it to appear in the Admin pages.

Comment: You should consider asking a new question if you need help with the module: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask